# Write to the same file using BufferWriter from multiple classes

Tags: java, filewriter

I want to output my result to a file. I use BufferWriter as below:

```
public class class1{
...
void print()
     {
     System.out.println("The name "+outName()+" Tel: "+outNumber());
       try{
          PrintWriter printWriter=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true)));
          printWriter.println("The name "+outName()+" Tel: "+outNumber());
        }catch (IOException e){}
       }

    }
```

However I have another class and main function also having their own print functions

```
public class class2{
    ...
    void print()
         {
         System.out.println("The name "+outName()+" Tel: "+outNumber());
           try{
              PrintWriter printWriter=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true)));
              printWriter.println("The name "+outName()+" Tel: "+outNumber());
            }catch (IOException e){}
           }

        }  

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

try{
    PrintWriter printWriter=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true)));
    ...
    printWriter.println("something");

printWriter.close();
    }catch(IOException e){ }

}
```

The code pass the compilation, but only the output from the main function appear in the output file. How to fix it please?

Comment: You probably want to use a logger like log4j or logback or java.util.logging instead of this.

Comment: `catch(IOException e){ }` No.  No no no.  Bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three (OK ... make that four, no five) significant problems with your code.

1. In `class2` you don't `close` or flush`the`PrintWriter` after you have finished writing.  That means that the data will never be written out to the file.  That's why you never see the output.

   This is the obvious bug.  But the rest of the problems are also important.  Arguably **MUCH MORE important** ... so keep reading.
2. The `print()` method in `class2` leaks file descriptors (!).  Each time you call it, it will open a file descriptor, write stuff ... and drop it on the floor.  If you call `print()` repeatedly, the `FileWriter` constructor will fail.  You *need* to close the file, and the cleanest way to ensure it always happens is to write the code like this:

   ```
   try (PrintWriter printWriter = 
            new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true)))) {
       printWriter.println(...);
   }
   ```

   This is a "try with resource" ... and it *guarantees* that the resource (`printWriter`) will be closed when the scope exits.
3. You are squashing exceptions.

   ```
   try {
       PrintWriter printWriter - ...
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // SQUASH!!!
   }
   ```

   **This is really, really bad**.  Basically, you have written your code to *ignore* the exception.  Pretend it never happened ... and throw away the information in the exception that would say *why* it happened.

   You should only ever squash an exception if you are *absolutely sure* that you will only catch expected exceptions, and that ignoring them is absolutely correct.  Here, it isn't.  If an `IOException` is thrown here, you *need* to know why!
4. Opening multiple streams to write to the same file is a recipe for problems.  The streams won't be synchronized, and you are likely to see the output interleaved in the output file in *unexpected* ways.  If the output pipelines include buffering (like yours do), the problem is worse.
5. You have serious Java style issues:

   - A class name should always start with an uppercase letter.  Always.  Even in example code snippets ...
   - Code should be consistently indented.  I recommend using SP characters rather than TAB characters because tabs don't display consistently.
   - There are style rules about where you should and should not put spaces and line breaks.  For example, there should always be whitespace around a binary operator.  Find a Java style guide, read it and format your code accordingly.

   Always write your code so that >>other people<< can read it.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're never closing anything exept in main(). You're also swallowing exceptions, so you're concealing the truth from yourself. Don't do that.

But it's poor practice. You should keep the file open and use the same FileWriter, BufferedWriter, PrintWriter, and synchronize access to them so you don't get interleaved data.

Not a good idea overall.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to call `new class1().print()` or `new class2().print()`, i.e. you need to instantiate the instances first.

Also please remember to close the file in each print() function.